# searching for part of a filename (UNIX)

Tags: unix, search, cut, inode

On unix I have files which have been renamed as their original name follwed by _inode number (ie the file dog would be renamed dog_inodeno).  I am now trying to remove the inode no so i can search for the original file name elsewhere.  Does anyone know how I can do this and teh coding neccesary.

Thanks

Comment: I imagine that the script that renamed the files could be slightly modified to rename those back.  No?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
find . -type f -name "*_[0-9]*" -exec \
  sh -c 'for i do
    b=$(basename "$i")
    r=$(basename "$i" "_$(ls -i "$i"|awk "{print \$1}")")
    if [ "$b" != "$r" ]; then 
      echo mv "$i" "$(dirname $i)/$r"
    fi
  done' sh {} +
```

Replace `echo mv` by `mv` for the script to actually rename the files.

Comment: basically all my filenames are formatted filename_inodeno and i want to create a script that cuts everything including and after the _.

Comment: This is precisely what the script I suggested is doing, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here will do rename your files only if the inode number of a file is part of the file's name in the mentioned format, which is what the OP wants.

Solution is successfuly tested at my end.

```
find ./ -name "*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" -exec sh 'rename-files.sh' {} \;
```

Store the below script for the find command to be successful.

```
#Script Name: rename-files.sh
#!/bin/bash

#Store the result of find
find_result=$1

#Get the existing file name
fname_alone=`expr ${find_result} : '.*/\(.*\)' '|' ${find_result}`
fname_with_relative_path=`expr ${find_result} : '.\(.*\)' '|' ${find_result}`
fname_with_full_path=`echo "$(pwd)${fname_with_relative_path}"`

#Get the inode number of file name
file_inode_no=`find ./ -name ${fname_alone} -printf '%i'`

#Read the end of name
end_of_name=`echo $fname_alone | awk -F "_" '{print $NF}' ` 

#Check if end of name contains its file's inode number
if [ $end_of_name -eq $file_inode_no ]
then
   #Remove the inode number at the end of file name 
   new_name=`expr $find_result : '.\(.*\)_.*' '|' $find_result`
   #Append the path of the file
   renamed_to=`echo "$(pwd)${new_name}"` 
   #Rename your dog_inodeno to dog
   mv $fname_with_full_path $renamed_to
fi
```

Hope this helps.